# Extremely slow calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write an equation that does the following things:

1) Integrates an equation

2) Stores that equation for later use

3) Numerically integrate the first and evaluate the 2nd equation on 100 different intervals, increasing by a fixed amount each time

```
import math
from sympy import *
import kvalues
import time
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The first task is very simple, I completed it like so:

```
def integration_gas(number,Fa_0,Fb_0,Fc_0,v_0,a,b,c,d,e):    
  Ca_0 = Fa_0/v_0
  Cb_0 = Fb_0/v_0
  Cc_0 = Fc_0/v_0
  Ft_0 = Fb_0 + Fa_0 + Fc_0
  theta1 = Cb_0/Ca_0
  stoic1 = b/a
  theta2 = Cc_0/Ca_0
  stoic2 = c/a
  stoic3 = d/a
  stoic4 = e/a
  Cd = stoic3*x
  Ce = stoic4*x
  sigma = e+d-c-b-1
  epsilon = (Fa_0/Ft_0)*sigma
  Ca_eq = Ca_0*((1-x)/(1+epsilon*x))
  Cb_eq = Ca_0*((1*theta1-stoic1*x)/(1+epsilon*x))
  Cc_eq = Ca_0*((1*theta2-stoic2*x)/(1+epsilon*x))                 
  ra = 1*(Ca_eq**a)*(Cb_eq**b)*(Cc_eq**c)*final_k[number-1]    
  equation = Fa_0/ra 
  int1 = Integral(equation,x)    
  pprint(int1)
  evaluate = int1.doit()     
  pprint(evaluate)
  return equation
```

This part of the code works perfectly fine, so on to the 2nd part.

```
def Ra_gas(number,Fa_0,Fb_0,Fc_0,v_0,a,b,c,d,e): 
    Ca_0 = Fa_0/v_0
    Cb_0 = Fb_0/v_0
    Cc_0 = Fc_0/v_0
    Ft_0 = Fb_0 + Fa_0 + Fc_0
    theta1 = Cb_0/Ca_0
    stoic1 = b/a
    theta2 = Cc_0/Ca_0
    stoic2 = c/a    
    sigma = e+d-c-b-1
    epsilon = (Fa_0/Ft_0)*sigma
    Ca_eq = Ca_0*((1-x)/(1+epsilon*x))
    Cb_eq = Ca_0*((1*theta1-stoic1*x)/(1+epsilon*x))
    Cc_eq = Ca_0*((1*theta2-stoic2*x)/(1+epsilon*x))                 
    ra = 1*(Ca_eq**a)*(Cb_eq**b)*(Cc_eq**c)*final_k[number-1]
    pprint(ra)
    return ra
```

This part of the code also works perfectly fine. So for the last part I have the following code:

```
Number = 4
FA0 = 10
FB0 = 25
FC0 = 5
V0 = 2
A = 1
B = 2
C = 0.5
D = 1
E = 1

Ra = []
volume = []
Xff = []
eq1 = integration_gas(Number,FA0,FB0,FC0,V0,A,B,C,D,E)
Ra1 = Ra_gas(Number,FA0,FB0,FC0,V0,A,B,C,D,E)
#print(Ra1)
Xf = 0.01

# Calculates the reaction rate and volume for every interval of conversion
while Xf <=1:
    int2 = Integral(eq1,(x,0,Xf))
    volume.append(int2.doit())
    f = lambdify(x,Ra1,"math")
    f(Xf)
    Ra.append(f(Xf))    
    Xff.append(Xf)
    Xf += 0.01
```

I then take the results and plot them. Everything i've written works perfectly fine for some situations and is completed in around 10~15 seconds. However, in situations like this one in particular, i've been running this code for 5+ hours with no solutions. How can I optimize this code?

Comment: try line profiler and find our which functions are critical. Think how to optimize it

Comment: Could you possibly explain in more detail? I'm new with coding, where can i read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at sympy, it can symbolically integrate your original equation and you then can evaluate it via numpy. For "real" maths Python is a bit slow, the scipy Stack (numpy, matplotlib, sympy...) is WAY faster.

Though 5+ hours is a bit long, are you sure that it actually executes?

EDIT: A simple thing to try
Sorry, Just now noticed you're lambdifying, you might want to include your imports so people see what you're using.

At the beginning:

```
import numpy as np
```

Let's go through this piece of your Code:

```
Xf = 0.01
while Xf <=1: 
    int2 = Integral(eq1,(x,0,Xf)) 
    volume.append(int2.doit()) 
    f = lambdify(x,Ra1,"math") #you're lambdifying each iteration that takes time
    f(Xf) # no assignment here, unless you're doing something in place this line does nothing
    Ra.append(f(Xf)) 
    Xff.append(Xf) 
    Xf += 0.01
```

With something along the lines of this:

```
Xf = np.arange(0.01, 1.01, 0.01) #vector with values from 0.01 to 1 in steps of 0.01
f = np.vectorize(lambdify(x,Ra1,"math")) # you anonymous function but able to take np vectors/np arrays
Ra = f(Xf)
#Xff would be Xf
```

Comment: I'm only on mobile and don't have the Integration syntax handy (I'd advise to read PEP8 or a Styleguide(for example the Google one), you generally don't want to import to namespace but rather "import sympy as sp" or something, that way people see you're using it and you don't get collisions.
I updated the original comment to include the usage of numpy.

If that still is too slow (which I doubt; I regularly run complex calculations for millions of values in seconds) you may want to have a look at `multiprocessing`

Comment: Yes it does eventually execute, but it takes a very long time. Is this not integrating with Sympy? How would i evaluate with numpy instead of lambda? Edit: Would i put that in the while loop or would it work on its own?

Comment: @TravisCzechorski
>Would i put that in the while loop or would it work on its own?
Nope, no while, just define the vector, lambdify and vectorize once and fire away.